# How to define methods on specific container types in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a `val list = List[Foo]()` and I want to define certain methods on this `List` but only when it is of type `Foo`, say `list.prettyDisplay()`.

Is that possible in Scala? I am looking at a tutorial on Advanced Types (http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/advanced-types.html) but I don't think I see what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an implicit conversion from `List[Foo]` to some class that implemets `prettyDisplay`. This conversion will not work for other lists because of the type of its parameter.

```
class Foo

implicit def betterFooList(l:List[Foo]) = new {
  def prettyDisplay() = ???
}

List(new Foo).prettyDisplay()
```